# How to get rid of 'Network' menu item in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I tried to delete it from context menu > Delete and it pops up Confirm Delete dialog and when I am pressing Yes - nothing happens.

I am using Win7 Ultimate SP1 64-bit.

[image]

Comment: Erm....  Why would you want to?

Comment: @Colyn1337 Because it disturbs me and I have many entries there and if it accidentally expanded it takes a while to load all list and also sometimes I got explorer opened with Network expanded so it again takes a while to load and looks like eyesore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Hiding the Network item in Windows Explorer

One way to do this is to use the Registry Editor.

1. Run `regedit` in the Start Menu search box.
2. Goto this key: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}\ShellFolder`
3. You will probably need to change the permissions of the `Shellfolder` key. Right-click it and select "Permissions." Give `Administrators` "Full Control." 
   [image: Permissions]
4. Back at the main regedit screen, change the value of the `Attributes` DWORD value to `b0940064`.
   [image: DWORD value adjusted]
5. Log off or reboot to make the change take effect. (Technically you need to restart explorer, so if you run Task Manager you can manually select Explorer and end it and then `File\New Task` it.)

Source: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-network-from-windows-7-explorers-navigation-pane/